# How to make username and password form work - where website cannot be seen by just typing in url

Tags: php, forms

So i have a website on a sever, and am using php code to access a 'log on' page where a person who has a username and password can add stuff to the website. But if you type the url in anyone can just access it without username and password. How do it change this.

So there is a form on html page, that has username and password fields, user types them in, php checks the info and the redirects to the correct page if the info is correct.

PHP code used

```
    <?php
    if ($_POST["usn"]=="ag316" || $_POST["psw"]=="rock") 
    {
        header("Location: addentry.html");
        exit();
    } 
    else
    {
        header("Location: login.html");
        exit();
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be better if you kept the username and passwords in a database and then just keep track of the users your site. But you will have to change `addentry.html` to `addentry.php` since you will need to run some php scripts on that page to track your users

You can set up a global sessions variable to track users. if the variable is not set, redirect the user to the login page, if the variable is set, allow them to access the page.

To add username to session variable;

```
$_SESSION["user"] = $username;
```

Then on every page that needs access, set an if statement

```
//start session
session_start();

 //check if session variable is set
 if(isset($_SESSION["user"])){
 }else{
     header('Location: login.php');
 }
```

Let me know if it helps.

Comment: keep in ming you will have to change your addentry.html page to PHP extension.

Comment: For more understanding about sessions:
https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp

Comment: @ThomasNikoleris that is correct.

Comment: Yes, this worked, thanks.